# I get uninitialized reference member with istream

Tags: c++

My professor gave me the following .h file as part of a programming assignment to make a lexer.

```
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

#include "token.h"
#include <istream>

class Lexer {
   public:
      Lexer(std::istream& input_stream);
      Token next_token();
   private:
      int current_line;
      int current_column;
      std::istream& input_stream;
};

#endif
```

I started making the .cpp file as shown below:

```
#include "lexer.h"

Lexer::Lexer(std::istream& inputstream){

}
```

When I try to compile, I get the error message:

```
lexer.cpp: In constructor ‘Lexer::Lexer(std::istream&)’:
lexer.cpp:4: error: uninitialized reference member ‘Lexer::input_stream’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is explicit : a reference member must be *initialized* in the member initialization list :

```
Lexer::Lexer(std::istream& inputstream) : input_stream(inputstream) {

}
```